# How to truncate the options text in select using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML looks like that:

```
<select>
 <option>Some option (description) (12)</option>
 <option>Some option (32)</option>
 <option>Some option (1)</option>
...
</select>
```

I need to get rid of the numbers in brackets at the end of it using jQuery or javascript. I'm stuck on this and I would really appreciate your help!

Thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 3):

The best solution could be is to do it in the server side where the select element is created.

If that is not possible then you could use a simple script which will update the text content of the option like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('select option').text(function(i, t) {
    return t.replace(/\(\d+\)\s*$/, '')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>Some option (description) (12)</option>
  <option>Some option (32)</option>
  <option>Some option (1)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, bit for some reason it doesnt work for me.

Comment: @EdytaKulaga check the update - I think the problem is the trailing spaces in the option content

Comment: In your option content there were spaces after `()`, but the regex was not handling those... now I have updated it - added `\s*` to regex

Answer (score 0):

by using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select option').each(function(){
        $(this).text(($(this).text()).replace(/\(\d+\)$/, ''))
    })
})
```

Comment: Here is my DEV, The triucky part is that im using ajax and select2

Comment: cvd.edyta.me/?page_id=12

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. The numbers are gone now!
You made my day cause I've been fighting with that for the last two days!

The fix was :

```
jQuery('select option').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).text((jQuery(this).text()).replace(/\(\d+\)\s*$/, ''))
})
```